# hoverIntent basic issue?

Tags: jquery, navigation, hoverintent

I've been pouring over the following code, trying to get the hoverIntent plugin to work, to no avail.
It's very basic stuff (if you have any consolidation ideas, please feel free) - .hover works fine, but .hoverIntent = no dice.

Basically, I just want a large img to change when a user mouses over a thumbnail, but to avoid wackiness, just wait a few before firing.

My jQuery (UPDATED AND WORKING MOSTLY) code:

```
function makeShow1(){ 
    $("#some-div img").hide();
    $(".uno").show();
}
function makeShow2(){ 
    $("#some-div img").hide();
    $(".dos").show();
}
function makeShow3(){ 
    $("#some-div img").hide();
    $(".tres").show();
}
function makeShow4(){ 
    $("#some-div img").hide();
    $(".quattro").show();
}
function makeShow5(){ 
    $("#some-div img").hide();
    $(".cinco").show();
}

function passOut() {
    $.(this).stop();
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".switch1").hoverIntent( {
        over: makeShow1,
        timeout: 500,
        interval: 300,
        out: passOut
    }); 

    $(".switch2").hoverIntent( {
        over: makeShow2,
        timeout: 500,
        interval: 300,
        out: passOut
    })

    $(".switch3").hoverIntent( {
        over: makeShow3,
        timeout: 500,
        interval: 300,
        out: passOut
    })

    $(".switch4").hoverIntent( {
        over: makeShow4,
        timeout: 500,
        interval: 300,
        out: passOut
    })

    $(".switch5").hoverIntent( {
        over: makeShow5,
        timeout: 500,
        interval: 300,
        out: passOut
    })

});

</script>
```

Comment: @collin i am using hoverintent and didn'run into any problem , you can refactor your code to take multiple classes in one hover function

Comment: @gov - you mean used hoverIntent on the example above and it worked? Hmmm...I've checked my path about a million times, and it's correct. What version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: @collin , no i used hoverintent plugin in my projects , it works pretty fine , jquery version is 1.4.

Comment: can you make sure you have class called .switch1.///just a check

Comment: @collin , can you try the example i gave below just for verfication...write two fucntions and just do a alert like mouseover and mouseout...

Comment: Yep - it's working, needed the out handler. Not working in IE6 though?

Answer (score 1):

Try this example

First please check if hoverintent is loaded properly , you can do that through firebug and later you can verify if there are any errors not..in firebug conole

create two functions and try below code to check if it is working.

```
  $('.classname').hoverIntent({
        over: functionname2,
        timeout: 500,
        interval: 300,
        out: functionname1
    });
```

Comment: ah, that's it - passing it the out handler worked. I actually created a fake function, since I don't want an onmouseout event to do anything really (imagine a giant picture with a gallery of thumbnails - you mouse over the thumbnail, the big one changes).

Comment: Here's my functions:      function passOut() {
   $.(this).stop();
  }function makeShow1(){ 
   $(".uno").show();
   $(".dos").hide();
   $(".tres").hide();
   $(".quattro").hide();
   $(".cinco").hide();
  }$(".switch1").hoverIntent( {
  over: makeShow1,
  timeout: 500,
  interval: 300,
  out: passOut
 });

Comment: @collin , do you need any more help or you can take from here...//

Comment: I think I got it, check my updated code (still no joy in IE6).

Comment: @thats great collin , the no of users using IE6 is very less nowadays , probably you can ignore or report to hoverintent as a feed back , before sending them verify whether your code is creating problem or plugin